# How to execute shell commands from Ruby in their own shell?

Tags: android, ruby, shell, adb

I'm writing a small Ruby script that performs some adb shell commands. The problem happens when I attempt to run a screen record on the android device and then send some swipe and touch events.

If I run adb shell `screenrecord` without an `"&"` at the end the touch and swipe, events only happen when the `screenrecord` times out:

```
adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/dumper.mp4
```

If I run it with an `"&"` at the end, the `screenrecord` cuts immediately when a touch or swipe event is carried out despite passing a high `--time-limit` option to `screenrecord`.

```
adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/dumper.mp4&
```

Is there a way I can just create a child process have it run the `screenrecord` and just dies when the `screenrecord` is finished and in parallel execute the touches and swipes?

I tried using `fork` but the parent ends up dying and if I re-exexcute the program the touches and swipes are carried out.

This is the code I used to fork:

```
def adb(arg)
    fork do
        exec("adb -s #{ARGV[0]} #{arg}")
        exit
    end
end
```

I tried looking at `spawn` as an alternative but it just wouldn't work:

```
  if line.include? "<record>"
  puts "comes here"
  duration=line.scan(/\d+/).first.to_i
  adb_sep("shell screenrecord --time-limit #{duration} /sdcard/demo.mp4")
```

It basically parses an XML file with tags to trigger a record process. I'm confident the exec isn't failing because I tried simulating the steps in IRB.

Running

```
irb>>exec(<adb screenrecord command>)
```

kills the Ruby shell after it is done as expected however.

```
irb>>system(<adb screenrecord command>&)
irb>>system(<adb tap or swipe command>)
```

works like a dream! It does exactly what I want it to do. Pulling the recorded video from the device shows exactly what I want.

---

I think I've figured out what's going on. Running adb with `&` sent the adb process to the background and recording stopped. Running adb tap brought it back to the foreground. consequently I'm getting chopped up videos.

I guess I would have to trigger the adb screenrecord in its own shell.

A bash analogy with a human would be to open one terminal, start recording the screeen. Open another terminal, start sending taps and swipes.

Comment: What was the code you were using to fork? Are you waiting on the child pids to finish?

Comment: I've added the code I used to fork. I specifically do not want to listen for child exits nor wait on/for them.

Comment: You don't really have much choice with fork you'll need to wait on all child pids otherwise the parent process will close and possibly leave zombie process.

Its as simple as adding `Process.wait` at the end of your code

Comment: The program is structured in such a way that the parent will always finish last. :(

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell whats going on from just a small code snippet. Are you sure the exec isn't failing?

Comment: When a question is answered successfully, it's not necessary, or even desired, to have '[SOLVED]' or anything similar added to the title. It's obvious it's solved when the answer is selected.

Comment: Sure. But I can't accept my own answer for two days. The solved I thought would be a good placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this was an Android shell screen record problem and not a Ruby problem.

Android is carrying out optimizations of recorded video length that skew my output video. It only records the video from the first UI change to the last UI change.